# In order to fill the properties of an object, what is more effective, to send the object as parameter to a method or return it from the method?

Tags: java, object

I have an object and I want to fill its properties inside of a method so, what is more effective, clean or according to any convention, to send the object as parameter (given that what I send is just a reference of the object) to the method or just declare inside the method an auxiliar object of that type, fill it, and return it?

For example, should I do this:

```
public class DataEntity{
    public void setProperty(Type value) {
    }
}

public class EntityBuilder {
    public configureEntity(DataEntity toConfig){}
}
```

or this:

```
public class DataEntity{
    public void setProperty(Type value) {
    }
}

public class EntityFactory {
    public DataEntity createEntity(){}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'effective and clean'? I would say the second option is more conventional, and probably makes more sense to the average user.

Comment: I don't really know what I mean, maybe in terms of resources or the most correct option.

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on your use case. With the second variant, you always create a new `DataEntity` object, while with the first variant, users could reuse a single instance of that class.

If the `DataEntity` objects are rather short-lived, but a lot of them will be created, the garbage collection might get busy cleaning up all the unused objects with the second variant. With the first variant, it's up to the user if they create a new instance every time or not.

The second variant is the more traditional one, and more often to be seen. It is also less error-prone. Consider the situation a user reuses a single instance, but at some point doesn't take care and gives that object to some other method which decides to keep a reference to it. That instance is now modified, and when the other method (or class of that method) looks at the stored reference, all values have changed!

For this reason, I'd suggest to use the second variant by default. The only case when I'd use the first variant is when know you will have millions of calls to `createEntity` that will create very short-lived objects and you are absolutely sure that none of the code dealing with such a `DataEntity` object will keep a reference to it. And even then, I'd first try to benchmark it to see if it really is a bottleneck. (Actually, I contribute to a large simulation framework which generates many millions of such simple Data objects, and for us, it was not yet worth the troubles to switch to the first variant as the gains would just be too small, but the chances of errors due to users keeping a reference to such an object too big)